# How do I create an image matrix with a line drawn in it in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, plot, line

I want to plot a line from one well-defined point to another and then turn it into an image matrix to use a Gaussian filter on it for smoothing. For this I use the functions `line` and `getframe` to plot a line and capture the figure window in an image, but `getframe` is very slow and not very reliable. I noticed that it does not capture anything when the computer is locked and I got an `out of memory` error after 170 executions.

My questions are:

- Is there a substitute to `getframe` that I can use?
- Is there a way to create the image matrix and draw the line directly in it?

Here is a minimal code sample:

```
figure1=line([30 35] ,[200 60]);
F= getframe;
hsize=40; sigma=20;
h = fspecial('gaussian',hsize,sigma); 
filteredImg = imfilter(double(F.cdata), h,256);
imshow(uint8(filteredImg));
```

**[update]**

High-Performance Mark's idea with `linspace` looks very promising, but how do I access the matrix coordinates calculated with `linspace`? I tried the following code, but it does not work as I think it should. I assume it is a very simple and basic MATLAB thing, but I just can not wrap my head around it:

```
matrix=zeros(200,60);
diagonal=round([linspace(30,200,numSteps); linspace(35,60,numSteps)]);
matrix(diagonal(1,:), diagonal(2,:))=1;
imshow(matrix);
```

Comment: So, what you are doing is rasterisation of a vector image.  Lots of good references on this topic, Wikipedia, as ever, is a good place to start.

Comment: I know, but I always try to use Matlab own functions. I don't learn as much, but they are faster and I don't have to spent time debugging them like my own code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one example of drawing a line directly into a matrix. First, we'll create a matrix of zeros for an empty image:

```
mat = zeros(250, 250, 'uint8');  % A 250-by-250 matrix of type uint8
```

Then, let's say we want to draw a line running from `(30, 35)` to `(200, 60)`. We'll first compute how many pixels long the line will have to be:

```
x = [30 200];  % x coordinates (running along matrix columns)
y = [35 60];   % y coordinates (running along matrix rows)
nPoints = max(abs(diff(x)), abs(diff(y)))+1;  % Number of points in line
```

Next, we compute row and column indices for the line pixels using [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), convert them from subscripted indices to linear indices using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), then use them to modify `mat`:

```
rIndex = round(linspace(y(1), y(2), nPoints));  % Row indices
cIndex = round(linspace(x(1), x(2), nPoints));  % Column indices
index = sub2ind(size(mat), rIndex, cIndex);     % Linear indices
mat(index) = 255;  % Set the line pixels to the max value of 255 for uint8 types
```

You can then visualize the line and the filtered version with the following:

```
subplot(1, 2, 1);
image(mat);        % Show original line image
colormap(gray);    % Change colormap
title('Line');

subplot(1, 2, 2);
h = fspecial('gaussian', 20, 10);  % Create filter
filteredImg = imfilter(mat, h);    % Filter image
image(filteredImg);                % Show filtered line image
title('Filtered line');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks gnovice for your comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you have Computer Vision System toolbox there is a ShapeInserter object available. This can be used to draw lines, circles, rectangles and polygons on the image.

```
mat = zeros(250,250,'uint8');
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape', 'Lines', 'BorderColor', 'White');
y = step(shapeInserter, mat, int32([30 60 180 210]));
imshow(y);
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.shapeinserterclass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14308558/411882). It is robust way to achieve what you are asking for. Advantage of my approach is that it doesn't need additional parameters to control *density* of the line drawn.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

[linspace(30,200,numSteps); linspace(35,60,numSteps)]

Does that work for you ?

Mark

Comment: Linspace looks very promising, but how do I access the matrix' coordinates calculated with linspace? I tried the last 30mins, but the following code does not work, as I think it should.. (scnr) I assume, it a very simple and basic Matlab thing, but I just can not wrap my head around it.
matrix=zeros(200,60);
diagonal=round([linspace(30,200,numSteps); linspace(35,60,numSteps)]);
matrix(diagonal(1,:), diagonal(2,:))=1;
imshow(matrix);