# Convert contour in a plot in matlab to a contour in image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have x and y coordinates of a contour. Now they cannot be used as pixel locations since they are not integers. I am unable to find a way to convert them into pixel locations. Floor and round functions do not help as they create blobs. I need a crisp contour similar as in a plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot your (x,y) points, remove axis ticks, and grab the axes into image. Try this:

```
figure;
plot(rand(10,1),rand(10,1));
box on; set(gca,'XTick',[],'YTick',[])
F = getframe(gca);
Image = F.cdata;
figure; imshow( Image );
```

**EDIT**:
If you need to draw many lines on image you may consider Bresenham's line algorithm to draw lines on image. See, for exmple, question and suggestions there:

- [How to draw a line on an image in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533843/how-to-draw-a-line-on-an-image-in-matlab)
- [MATLAB: Drawing a line over a black and white image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464637/matlab-drawing-a-line-over-a-black-and-white-image)

Comment: I am already aware of this technique. However, I do not prefer using this as it will slow down my code a lot further since I am doing all this in a loop. I will have to close the figure each time which will cause flickering.

Please suggest a solution to this. Thanks!!