# How to draw a line on an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, line, draw

I have two points lets say:

- P(x,y) [point lies at the top of image]
- P'(x',y') [point lies at bottom of image]

Now i want to draw a line betwen these two points....and the line should appear on image means should be visible.

how to do this????

Comment: I believe what you're asking has been covered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940833/how-do-i-create-an-image-matrix-with-a-line-drawn-in-it-in-matlab, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464637/matlab-drawing-a-line-over-a-black-and-white-image, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178336/matlab-how-to-plot-x-y-on-image-and-save, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575475/how-can-i-save-an-altered-image-in-matlab

Comment: It's almost an exact duplicate, but not quite.

Comment: Have a look at the following two links: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/07/22/graphical-display-techniques-part-1/ http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/08/05/graphical-display-techniques-part-2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464637/matlab-drawing-a-line-over-a-black-and-white-image

this link you gave works for binary images only...and my image is not binary.

and rest of the links are not for my use.so i need something different.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way to draw a line onto an image is to use [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html).

```
%# read and display image
img = imread('autumn.tif');
figure,imshow(img)

%# make sure the image doesn't disappear if we plot something else
hold on

%# define points (in matrix coordinates)
p1 = [10,100];
p2 = [100,20];

%# plot the points.
%# Note that depending on the definition of the points,
%# you may have to swap x and y
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
```

If you want a different color, either change the letter to any of `rgbcmykw`, or use RGB triplets  (red is `[1 0 0]`). Have a look at the [lineseries properties](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/lineseriesproperties.html) for more formatting options.

Comment: chee: a) that is a different question, b) use point-slope formula for a line.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with version R2014a you can use insertShape as follows:

`img = insertShape(img,'Line',[x1 y1 x2 y2],'LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');`

You can also draw multiple lines with the same command, but x1,x2,y2,y3 must be column vectors with each row representing a new line.

*insertShape* also allows you to draw rectangles, circles, and polygons.

Comment: This only works if you have the Computer Vision Toolbox.  Can you suggest a method without using it?

Comment: How to use dotted lines?

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
figure;
hold on;
imagesc(img);
line([x1,x2],[y1,y2],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
hold off
```

Where y is the "down" direction and x is the "right" direction in the image. Change the color and width as necessary to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
load clown
image(X)
colormap(map)
c = size(X,2)
mid = round(c/2)
X(:,mid) = 1
image(X)
```

Comment: If it is a color image, you should use `X(:,mid,:) = [1 1 1];`.

Comment: It is a vertical line.  Slope is infinite.

Comment: It would be easy (not difficult) but more fun to draw a line in the opposite color (RGB) of the background image color along the line...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Computer Vision toolbox. You can simply use shapeInserter.

Check out  http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.shapeinserter-class.html

To specify lines, you have to use the line below. Otherwise, you may get a rectangle

Example:

```
%draw a line from point (100,100) to (200,200) on an image saved as nextFrame

line = int32([100 100  200 200]);
shapeInserter = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape', 'Lines');
nextFrame = step(shapeInserter, nextFrame, line);
```

Take a look at the properties to see what you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could download and use [hline and vline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039-hline-and-vline) in conjunction with `hold on`, using the techniques from visiting [Steve on Image Processing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/01/01/superimposing-line-plots/). Or just use his techniques. Either way it works.