# How to programmatically draw a line in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, charts, figure

I am trying to draw an arbitrary ***line*** on a figure in matlab (off of a plot) and I don't know what command I can use.

I tried using the [arrow](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m) package, but I'm getting bad results

Comment: Here's a relevant question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533843/how-to-draw-a-line-on-an-image-in-matlab

Comment: Have a look at [Bresenham's Line](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12939-bresenhams-line).

Comment: annotation(figure(3),'line',[0 .5],   [.5 0.574759945130315]);

Comment: no idea why people are downvoting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `line` function and set the `clipping` property to `off` to draw a line that is visible outside the axis. The x and y coordinates of line will be in the coordinates of the axis and you may need to change the axis limits.

Comment: I had to actually use the arrow command otherwise there is no way to try and reference a point relative to the graph, it just relative to the figure.