# Draw line using two points over whole image in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, line

I need Matlab code to draw a line on an image using two points not just between those points put on the whole image and then check if the pixels are on right of the image then make its value 0 = black else stay as is
I am not proffesional at matlab and need this for a project.
[image]

Comment: Did you try something? Could you show an example of what you need?

Comment: No I did not try, I did not know where to start!

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html
here you can find how to get the line equation from two points.
Also, the left and right parts of the 2D-plane seperated by the line are determined by taking the inequality of the equation `y>ax+b` and `y<ax+b`. Saying that you didn't try anything yet, these hints can give you a point to start.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing a line on the image other than an annotation line has been covered in other questions on SO, see an example here: [How to draw a line on an image in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3533843/2777181)

If you want to go that path, I would draw the line on a black image and generate a binary mask out of it. Then apply the mask as I mention it below.

Now, if you are looking for a quick fix, here is an idea:

```
BW=roipoly(i1);
```

Then draw a polygon that encloses the left part of your image and stops at the line. You will get something like that:

[image: Binary mask]

Now clean it up a bit

```
Mask=imdilate(BW, [1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1; 1 1 1 1 1]);
```

And apply the mask to the 3 layers of your RGB image:

```
Masked(:,:,1)=i1(:,:,1).*Mask;
Masked(:,:,2)=i1(:,:,2).*Mask;
Masked(:,:,3)=i1(:,:,3).*Mask;
imshow(Masked);
```

Result:

[image: masked]