# generate synthetic data 2d x t x v using matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, simulation, mesh, synthetic

i am trying to generate/simulate a set of synthetic/ simulated data set to generate a synthetic blood flow image in matlab. but i dont know how or where to starts from...

i know i should use the mesh function but how do i make it so it could be in time dimension?

I will be very thankful if anybody could help/ guide me through. I want to generate a data set of size 25x25x10x4. Which is X x Y x t x V. The image should be something similar to this:

[image: this is an image of supposedly vessel in the brain]

or like this:

[image]

thank you in advance!

Comment: if you are significantly changing the original post, please indicate that as an "update", or provide further clarifications. Otherwise the provided answers may no longer make sense.

Comment: Please stop destroying your question. Not only will the answers no longer make sense, it is also disrespectful and undermines the effort people put in to help you.

Answer (score 3):

#### Dataset #1:

Use your favorite line representation (polar, linear, whatever) and randomly generate the parameters for your line. E.g. if you go for `y = mx + c`, randomly generate `m` and `c`. Now that you have defined your line, [use this SO method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941310/71131) to draw it on the image.

[image]

#### Dataset #2:

They look like 2D Gaussians. Use [`mvnpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html) in the following manner.

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(x_range,y_range);
Z = reshape(  mvnpdf([X(:) Y(:)],MU,SIGMA)   ,size(X));
imagesc(Z);
```

Use  some randomly generated `MU` and `SIGMA` such that `MU` lies in `x_range` and `y_range`. E.g. `x_range = -3:0.1:3;y_range = x_range;` and

> MU =
>
> ```
> 0.9575    0.9649
> ```
>
> SIGMA =
>
> ```
> 1.2647    0.3760
> 0.3760    1.0938
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement @Jacob 's very specific answer, you need a 4D `MxNxTxV` matrix. In this, according to the post, `MxN` is the dimension of each image, `T` is the time dimension, and V is the number of channels or samples per time frame (3 for RGB or >3 for any spectral image).

- For each T, generate V images.
- Simulate the V images with random parameters for Dataset #1 and Dataset #2.
- Put everything in one 4D matrix per Dataset (i.e. using a double for or concatenation)

Replace `rand()` with `generate_image()` below, i.e. a function generating random samples of the type of structure you want, according to @Jacob 's suggestions:

```
M = 25; N = 25;
T = 10; V = 4;

DataSet1 = zeros(M,N,T,V);
DataSet2 = zeros(M,N,T,V);

for t = 1:T
   for v = 1:V
        DataSet1(:,:,t,v) = randn(M,N);
        DataSet2(:,:,t,v) = randn(M,N);
    end
end
```